# Non-Yielding scheduler errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance

Suddenly today we started seeing non-yeilding scheduler errors on SQL 2008 R2 failover cluster. We are unable to connect so we had to restart the SQL services and everything is back to normal now.

I did some research and found a Microsoft connect item and users reporting this issue but not sure if there was fix and not entirely sure if it's because of backups but i do see log backups running during this time frame
and we do use SQL native compression option for backups.

Microsoft announced a fix for (please see the fix URL below) and we are in SQL 2008 R2 SP3 but they had the fix in SP2. not sure why we are still seeing the issue, based on the cause provided in fix url (This issue occurs because the profiling session is not closed correctly. The profiling session is used to calculate the cost of an object to be cached, and is based on memory usage and CPU usage.), i'm thinking this has something to do with our SQL Sentry profiling session. We use Idera SQL dm for monitoring and we are also testing SQL sentry and i do see some sql sentry login failures around this time frame.

Can anyone shed some light on this ?

Here are the error details:

> Process 0:0:0 (0x1184) Worker 0x0000000110D6A1A0 appears to be
>   non-yielding on Scheduler 9. Thread creation time: 13137300580167.
>   Approx Thread CPU Used: kernel 327 ms, user 37487 ms. Process
>   Utilization 58%. System Idle 38%. Interval: 80545 ms. Process 0:0:0
>   (0x1184) Worker 0x0000000110D6A1A0 appears to be non-yielding on
>   Scheduler 9. Thread creation time: 13137300580167. Approx Thread CPU
>   Used: kernel 483 ms, user 66316 ms. Process Utilization 57%. System
>   Idle 39%. Interval: 140747 ms.

- [Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/521928/worker-w-appears-to-be-non-yielding-on-scheduler-s)
- [FIX for similar issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2699013/fix-sql-server-2012,-sql-server-2008-r2-or-sql-server-2008-stops-responding-and-a-non-yielding-scheduler-error-is-logged)

Comment: I would start [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/sos_scheduler_yield/) by Paul Randal.

Comment: Thanks...I already looked at this, i will look once again....but if can anyone confirm this is not a bug ?

Comment: My advise would be to open case with Microsoft, and yes before that applying latest CU released after SP3 to check whether issue is resolved in subsequent CU would also be a correct thing to do